# Особенности работы процессов. Не работает print из процесса

Tags: python

Изучаю Python. В учебном примере по multiprocessing добавил отладочную печать в процесс. Сам пример заработал, а вот печать 'test message' из процесса не работает. В аналогичном примере с потоками печать из потока работает.
Поиск не помог. Просьба пояснить, почему не работает, или что умное прочитать:-)

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

def sq(value, q):
    print('test message')
    q.put(value**2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    number = 2
    q = Queue()
    proc = Process(target=sq,args=(number, q))
    proc.start() 
    proc.join() 
    while not q.empty():
        print(q.get(), end="  ")
```

Comment: https://docs-python.ru/standart-library/paket-multiprocessing-python/klass-queue-modulja-multiprocessing/

Comment: Спасибо, но не понимаю, где там найти ответ на мой вопрос. Я собственно, и отрабатывал пример, глядя в подобный документ. У меня что-то совсем примитивное не работает? (я не голову имею в виду:-))

Comment: вроде работает как задумано

Comment: создай еще пару Process.  number в созднанных Process сделай разный

Comment: спасибо, создал, результаты выводит исправно (3 процесса с number 2, 3, 4 дают строку 4 9 16), а вот 'test message' так ни разу и не напечатался. Перегрузил IDLE - не помогло. 
Я правильно понимаю, что это только на моей машине слова "test message" функция не печатает, а на другой машине они вполне себе напечатались при запуске моего кода?

Comment: На моей машинке печатает test message. Попробуйте код в онлайн сервисе https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_python_debugger

Comment: Спасибо большое за проверку и совет, в сервисе тоже печатает. У меня вполне приличный ноутбук HP, Windows 10, все обновления (сейчас дообновил и перегрузил - не помогло), доп.программ очень мало. Очень странное поведение. Нет идеи, чтобы это могло значить, и на что я могу наткнуться при дальнейшей работе c Python? Я довольно давно не занимался программированием, так что даже сравнить не с чем.

Comment: Какое у вас IDLE? версия пайтон?

Comment: IDLE Shell 3.10.2

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135240/discussion-between---and-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выяснилось в результате, что печать в потоке не работает у меня исключительно в IDLE Shell 3.10.2. На внешнем сайте отладки работает, в PyCharm 2021 3.3. Community Edition (специально установил) работает.

Обновление ответа: проблема встречалась не у меня одного.
Нашел пояснение на overcoder.net: "Это проблема с IDLE, которую вы используете для запуска кода. IDLE выполняет довольно базовую эмуляцию терминала для обработки вывода программы, которую вы запускаете в ней. Однако он не может обрабатывать подпроцессы, поэтому, пока они будут работать в фоновом режиме, вы никогда не увидите их вывод. Самое простое решение - просто запустить ваш код из командной строки. Альтернативой может быть использование более сложной среды IDE."

Огромное спасибо @Сергей Шашко, который и у себя всё проверял, и мне
посоветовал PyCharm и прочее!

Очень важный для меня (и, возможно, для других новичков) **вывод: не работает в базовой среде - не зацикливаться на ней, пробовать в других средах.**